# regex - remove pattern from nested comma separated list

Tags: regex

I have nested comma separted list from which I need to remove specific patterns.

e.g.

```
{pattern1=10-abc,pattern2=xyz,pattern3={pattern4-1=abc-123,pattern4=abc-123},pattern5=xyz}
```

so for example I want to remove pattern4 and pattern5 and get result:

```
{pattern1=10-abc,pattern2=xyz,pattern3={pattern4-1=abc-123}}
```

if I use --> `matchpattern+"=.*?,"` I can remove all ending with "," but then I will loose one "}" and not remove pattern5 in above example:

```
{pattern1=10-abc,pattern2=xyz,pattern3={pattern4-1=abc-123,pattern5=xyz}
```

I could also live with not removed "," after "}":

```
{pattern1=10-abc,pattern2=xyz,pattern3={pattern4-1=abc-123},}
```

Thank you in advance!

P.S.
with `pattern(1|4|5)=.*?[,}]` I have matched everything I need. 
Is there a way to replace with "" if matched pattern ended with "," and replace with "}" if ended with "}"?

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/96Iwbk/1

Comment: Your before and after `{pattern1=10-abc,pattern2=xyz,pattern3={pattern4-1=abc-123  <remove> }  <remove> }` have no analogy to remove anything. What is the relationship which removes these and _not_ the others ?

Comment: If `pattern(?:1|4|5)=.*?(?:,|(}))` is used,
before: `{pattern1=10-abc,pattern2=xyz,pattern3={pattern4-1=abc-123,pattern4=abc-123},pattern5=xyz}`

after: `{pattern2=xyz,pattern3={pattern4-1=abc-123,},}`

still one comma, before pattern4 is not removed

Comment: thank you Wiktor... your solution was very helpful (problem with comma resolved on the other way)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
,?pattern(4|5)=[\w-]+
```

Comment: thanks... almost working fine...
but if I want to remove pattern1, comma after pattern1 is not removed

Comment: and one more thing, after "=" there can be any character(s) (except "," or "}" which are delimiters)